# Android Studio: Gradle: error: cannot find symbol variable

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I was working on my app and everything was normal until I tried to display image in java.

I ran the app once and it ran normally, the picture was displayed.
After that it asked me to import some libraries and I imported them. After that I got errors for my activities.

Errors like:

```
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol variable activity_main
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol variable button1
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol variable button2
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol variable textView
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol variable secondActivity
```

In MainActivity I have imported these libraries:

```
import android.R;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
```

and in secondActivity these:

```
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT: I deleted `import android.R;` and now it works normally.

Comment: A Gradle resync fixed this for me.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You shouldn't be importing `android.R`.  That should be automatically generated and recognized.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error?rq=1) contains a lot of helpful tips if you get some error referring to `R` after removing the import.

Some basic steps after removing the import, if those errors appear:

- Clean your build, then rebuild
- Make sure there are no errors or typos in your XML files
- Make sure your resource names consist of `[a-z0-9.]`.  Capitals or symbols are not allowed for some reason.
- Perform a Gradle sync (via Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files)

Comment: Manually declaring the "import com.your.app.package.name.R" fixed the "cannot find symbol variable" for me. But this was after i had copied a class from a module into the main app project in Android Studio and Gradle failed to build. But I would suggest trying the above options first, as that is the likely case for this error.

Comment: I had similar problem currently. The problem was that in my project I had more modules. E.g. `com.packagename.app` module and `com.packagename.library` module. Although both, the class and the `R.string` resource were from the `com.packagename.app` module I somehow had `import com.package.library.R` in the class. Somehow Android Studio did not recognize this as an error and Gradle/Sync build my project without problems. But when I tried to run Unit Tests Gradle build failed with the described error.

Removing the `import com.packagename.library.R` solved my problem.

Comment: Note: underscore `_` can also be used in resource id's

Comment: Actually, you do need to import R if the class you are working on is not in the application package.

Comment: You just saved me. I moved a class from a module to main app folder and also the strings from the module and I couldn't understand why the strings are not found in the class I moved. Issue: the class imported R from the module, not from the app. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 25):

If you are using ***multiple flavors***?

> -make sure the resource file is not declared/added both in only one of the flavors and in main.

Example: `a_layout_file.xml` file containing the symbol variable(s)

**src:**

flavor1/res/layout/(no file)

**flavor2**/res/layout/`a_layout_file.xml`

**main**/res/layout/`a_layout_file.xml`

This setup will give the error: cannot find symbol variable, this is because the resource file can only be in both flavors **or** only in the main.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using a `String` build config field in your project, this might be the case:

```
buildConfigField "String", "source", "play"
```

If you declare your String like above it will cause the error to happen. The fix is to change it to:

```
buildConfigField "String", "source", "\"play\""
```

Answer (score 2):

Open project in android studio
click file
and click Invalidate Caches/Restart

Answer (score 1):

make sure that the imported R is not from another module. I had moved a class from a module to the main project, and the R was the one from the module.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `MainActivity` and `.ScanActivity` into your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ScanActivity">

    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your variables are in scope for the method that is referencing it. For example I had defined a textview locally in a method in the class and was referencing it in another method.

I moved the textview definition outside the method right below the class definition so the other method could access the definition, which resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to @TouchBoarder's answer above is that you may also have two layout files with the same name but for different api versions. You should delete the older my_file.xml file

```
my_file.xml
my_file.xml(v21)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the control you are referring to in the XML layout file really exists, even if it's not being used.

I had this after when I did "removed unused resources" refactory.

For example, you will get this error if there is no progressBar in the layout.

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stats, container, false);

mProgressBar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check you accidentally added the XML file into the layout folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure your package name correct at top, wrong package name may cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's an interoperability issue, for example, the class not found may be a .java file not .kt