# Android Studio - Android TV activity wizard broken?

Tags: android-studio, android-tv

I have already an Android app in Android Studio and i am trying to make it Android TV compatible. Therefore, i tried to create an Android TV activity (that is using the Leanback support library) using the new activity wizard (File -> New -> Activity -> ANdroid TV activity). The wizard is finishing successfully but the project is full of errors! I am attaching a screenshot with the errors.

[image]

Comment: are you importing any libraries? Also, have you had a chance to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154499/android-studio-gradle-error-cannot-find-symbol-variable)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using many libraries and they are fine before adding the Android TV activity. I am listing them in case it helps: butterknife, volley, gson, picasso, rangebar, cardslib.

I have looked at the link you provided but i do not have imported android.R anywhere and a full Gradle re-sync does not fixes the issue.

Thank you again for your suggestion.

Comment: How are you declaring your new activity in the manifest? E.g. Have you followed these steps shown [here](http://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html#dev-project)? Just trying to understand what's wrong. To me it seems you skipped some step somewhere. But that's just my personal experience with such an error.

Comment: I have used the new activity wizard from Android Studio; that is File -> New -> Activity -> Android TV activity. I doubled check with your link and everything is declared as it should. I think that the wizard is not creating some resources like the layouts that are referred.