# Android Studio | cannot resolve existing drawable

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-resources

I'm getting error while compile gradle project

```
Error:(128, 35) error: cannot find symbol variable ic_contact_picture
```

but such resource is most definitely available, Android Studio even show me picture of that resource in left border

[image: Android Studio snippet]

I tried clean, build, rebuild, restart or sync Studio/project, as advised i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154499/android-studio-gradle-error-cannot-find-symbol-variable), all without success.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please try another pic from your drawable folder not android one like `R.drawable.myimage` and tell us the result

Comment: I'm not seeing that drawable in android studio. Just download a graphic and put it in your drawable folder then use that.  R.drawable.mygraphic

Comment: From autocomplete I can choose i.e. `android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email` and then it works. But I want picture of user, so I found nice user picture `ic_contact_picture`, Android Studio does not offer it to me in autocomplete, but I know it's there, because Android Studio can find and show me the drawable, but, it cannot compile project with such resource. I don't understand why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `R` class from the Android system, i.e. `android.R`. If the drawable `ic_contact_picture` is your own picture, then you want to use `R.drawable.ic_contact_picture` instead, without the `android.` prefix.

If you intended to use the Android system drawable, you have to copy the specific drawable to your app, since the `ic_contact_picture` is not made public by the SDK.

Comment: I want use android picture, I'm lazy to create my own :)

Comment: @Vaclav this specific drawable is not public, so you cannot access it. If you want to use it, you have to copy it into your app.

Comment: So google don't want to share it with me. I thought I just can use arbitrary android resource. In that case, I'll copy it, although I don't think that its a good pattern to duplicate resources. Thank you!