# Variables Cannot contain $ after Android Studio update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I've updated my Android Studio to 3.0 version, Android gradle plugin to `3.0.0` version (`com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0`), support libraries to 27.0.0 version and **buildTools** to `26.0.2` at once.

After that updates I get a lot of errors during builds but all of them are linked with symbol variables:

```
HostsListAdapter.java
Error:(42, 40) error: cannot find symbol variable i_computer_$rr
Error:(43, 40) error: cannot find symbol variable i_computer_$iv
Error:(44, 40) error: cannot find symbol variable i_computer_$tv
```

I didn't change anything in my application since last successful build. What I should do to fix this errors? Of course resources exist, moreover they are visible in code tips while typing.

I've tried few times to clean and rebuild the project or sync gradle with no results.

Comment: Please follow this answer steps [Variable not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18154713/745754)

Comment: I've forgot to mention about it, but I've made all those steps.

Comment: @SamyMassoud you were right, I checked the answer once again and error occurs because there are $ signs in var name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats  because from Android studio 3.0 onwards the compiler complains if there is a $ in the variable name **rename it without special character** everything should work fine. I have the same issue still unclear why the has been Incorporated

Comment: I answerd my question in comment but I mark this as solution for others with the same issue.

Comment: Oh didn't see you there,