# How to fix: "Cannot find symbol variable" for TextClock

Tags: java, android, time, clock

I am trying to put a `TextClock` into my application to display the time formatted like so: 8:23 PM.

I set the `minSdkVersion` in the `build.gradle` file to 17 and synced the project so that I can use `TextClock` in my app. In the .xml file I set the `TextClock` id to `clock`. In the .java Activity file I inflated the view in the `onCreate()` method. I have tried invalidating/restarting caches, and cleaning/rebuilding the project and nothing has resolved the problem.

**build.gradle** file

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.agilysys.mobconceirge"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

**ReservationListActivity.java** file

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reservations_list);
    textClock = (TextClock) findViewById(R.id.clock);
}
```

**activity_reservations_list.xml** file

```
<TextClock
    android:id="@+id/clock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:format12Hour="h:mm:ss a"
    android:textColor="@color/penRoyalBlue"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

When I go to build the compiler is giving me the error: "cannot find symbol variable clock".

Comment: could you please post all ReservationListActivity.java file

Comment: Did you declare textClock  in your activity class file?

Comment: yes I did declare it in the activity class file, I don't know why it is not working because I do this all the time and it is just giving me an error from the TextClock @p_anatha

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154499/android-studio-gradle-error-cannot-find-symbol-variable